# CVE-2021-20289 - migrate from Resteasy jaxrs 3 to RESTEasy > 4.6.0

Tags: resteasy, cve

The vulnerability scan system detects a CVE regarding RestEasy 3.7.0: CVE-2021-20289
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-20289, which states RESTEasy should upgrade to above 4.6.0.Final. But, here comes the question: RESTEasy > 4 does not contains this submodule.

I noticed that in https://developer.jboss.org/en/resteasy/blog/2019/03/28/resteasy-4-is-coming-soon, it is stated that

> the big resteasy-jaxrs and resteasy-client modules have been split into resteasy-core-spi, resteasy-client-api, resteasy-core and resteasy-client, with the first and second ones to be considered as public modules, for which we're expected to retain backward compatibility till next major release.

If I comment out the resteasy-jaxrs dependency from pom.xml, I will get error of `cannot access class org/jboss/resteasy/microprofile/config/ResteasyConfigFactory`. But I cannot find it in resteasy-core-spi or rest-client-api module. The nearest is `resteasy-4.7.4.Final/resteasy-core-spi/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/config/ConfigurationFactory.java`. But if the class name changed, there would not be easy migration. Or am I missing something?

Actually according to https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY-2878, this CVE is fixed in 3.15.2. So I am lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I

- migrate from resteasy 3 to 4, abandon `resteasy-jaxrs` and introduce `resteasy-client-api` and `resteasy-client`
- switch from `org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder` to `org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ResteasyClientBuilderImpl`, even though it's under `internal` package, it's a public class and Javadoc does not suggest against using it directly. And this implementation is quite standard, and introduces the minimal fraction while migrating. I also compared the default values set in the class, such as connectionPoolSize and so on, they are the same as in resteasy-jaxrs 3.

The code change is minimal:

```java
// before
    private ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
            .connectionPoolSize(CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE)
            .build();
// after
    private ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilderImpl()
            .connectionPoolSize(CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE)
            .build();
```

---

And the provider:

I am receiving content type `text/plain`. In Resteasy-jaxrs 3, I used `ResteasyJackson2Provider` and it implements `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter`, and it worked. Now, in Restyeasy 4, the content type check seems to be stricter and `isReadable()` of this same named class only accepts `Content-Type` of `null` or contains `json`. As I receive `text/plain`, it no longer works.

For reading plain text, I suggest using `StringTextStar`. A new class in Resteasy 4.7.5, and it seems to work. Reading inputstream and write as string, just what I need. Check its impl.

```
ResteasyClient client1 = new ResteasyClient()
                          .register(new ResteasyJackson2Provider()) // for JSON
                          .build();
ResteasyClient client2 = new ResteasyClient()
                          .register(new StringTextStar()) // for text/plain
                          .build();
```

---

And the auto-closeable client:

Now you need to use try-finally or try-with-resources to close it. It will be closed automatically if you don't, but you receive a warning: `Closing an instance of ApacheHttpClient43Engine for you` and so.